# AFNetworking not building the correct URL?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Starting to look into iOS and am in need of Restful networking so I'm looking at AFNetworking. I've followed some good examples and I think I understand how to use it but the request that gets built does not have the expected URL.
In AFHTTPClient requestWithMethod path parameters method,

```
po urlBase
$0 = 0x003b23b8 https://mysite.com/developer/api
(lldb) po url
$1 = 0x1eddf140 /users/current -- https://mysite.com/developer/api/
(lldb) po request
$2 = 0x1ed50580 <NSMutableURLRequest https://mysite.com/users/current>
```

The developer section is getting stripped for some reason.

I've seen examples where the relative path string passed into the getPath method has a leading slash and therefore one would expect the base URL to not have a trailing slash but I've seen examples where folks put a slash in both.

My base URL var is

```
NSString *const ServiceUrlBaseProduction  = @"https://mysite.com/developer/api/";
```

and the relative path to get current user is

```
@"/users/current";
```

Comment: Why are you including the leading slash for a relative path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of `AFHTTPSessionManager`'s interpretation of URLs. In `AFHTTPSessionManager.h` [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/36bccffd5d9da855b6cd624ae582f72841cbabe2/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h#L67-L73) there is an explanation of how to write your URLs correctly. I believe you will want to get the current user with the path `users/current` instead (without the leading slash)

Comment: yeah, so even if i leave the trailing slash off the base url, the url will have it anyway, and if i leave the leading slash off my relative path, the url build appropriately.

Comment: Exactly. I agree that it's confusing behavior

Comment: The link is now a 404, and I think AFHTTPClient.h is no longer there. An explanation of how to write URLs is found in the source of [AFHTTPSessionManager.h](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h) though

Comment: I've updated the link and pointed it to the most recent commit so the link won't break again, although it might become outdated.

Answer (score 0):

try using NSURL:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.com/developer/api/"];
```

Then:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"users/current" relativeToURL:url];
```

Comment: i'm trying to build a client that inherits from AFHTTPClient. My init initializes itself using NSURL. [self = [super initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLwithString:[[self class] urlBase]]]...